# Using max value as a filter

Tags: mysql

I'm having issues writing a MySQL query. It's actually a pretty large one, and the part I'm having issues with is about this *User_City* table :

```
| user_id | int(11)
| city_id | int(11)
| from    | date
| to      | date
```

I would like to compare the ID of the city in which the user we're looking for currently lives, with the ID provided by the user performing the research. I have something like this :

```
User_City.user_id=User.id and User_City.city_id='.$city_id.' and...
```

Now the problem is writing the last part where I specify that I want to compare the ID of the most recent entry, meaning the line in which the *from* field has the highest value but the *user_id* is still the same.

Comment: `ORDER BY from DESC LIMIT 1` will get the most recent row that matches the criteria.

Comment: If you're getting results for multiple users and you need the max row for each, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1